# How to map array to new single object in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I'm doing this:

```
const rawValues = this.filterList.map(s => {
     return {[s.filterLabel]: s.selectedOption}
  });
```

`filterList` variable has this type:

```
export interface SelectFilter {
  filterLabel: string;
  options: Observable<any>;
  selectedOption: string;
}
```

now `rawValues` is being mapped like this:

```
[
{filterLabel: selectedOption},
{filterLabel: selectedOption},
{filterLabel: selectedOption}
]
```

so it's an array of my new objects,

but what I want is a SINGLE object, so the end result should be:

```
{
filterLabel: selectedOption,
filterLabel: selectedOption,
filterLabel: selectedOption
}
```

NOTE that "`filterLabel`" will always be unique.

What do I need to change in the `map()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case, a map isn't needed as it would result in creating a new array which is unnecessary. Just iterate over each element in the array then assign each filterLabel as a new key to the obj like this:

```
const obj = {};
this.filterList.forEach(s => {
  obj[s.filterLabel] = s.selectedOption;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: this indeed outputs exactly what I need....I really thought I had to use a Map() for some reason...thank you

Comment: const is a bad idea in this case!
use var or let

Comment: @i-HmD what do you suggest?

Comment: const wouldn't restrict adding a new key to the object :P

Comment: @AJ989 let or var

Comment: @HeinrichDonZ.Abad yeah, but gives the wrong intention! :D

Comment: @i-HmD i see your point. well you might be better off with "let"

Comment: Given that the object likely won't be re-assigned anymore, `const` *would*, in fact, be the better choice. Use `let` over `const`, if you do plan on re-assigning the value of a variable afterwards. Use `var` over `let`, if you need a global (hoisted) variable. Rules of thumb.

Comment: updated my answer with reduce alternative :)

Comment: readability matters a lot aside from the fact that it carries more overhead for a very simple problem

Answer (score 1):

I think this is use case for array reduce:

```js
let result =
[{filterLabel: 'label1', selectedOption: 'option1'}, {filterLabel: 'label2', selectedOption: 'option2'}, {filterLabel: 'label3', selectedOption: 'option3'}, {filterLabel: 'label4', selectedOption: 'option4'} ]
.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return { 
    [currentValue.filterLabel]: currentValue.selectedOption,
    ...previousValue }
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

More details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do anything to get the result you want.  First, when you run a map on the array, a new array is returned.  To change that you would have to re-write the map function with your own.  Technically possible, but not recommended.

Second, you cannot have multiple properties on an object that have the exact same name.  I know of no way around this.

You might be able to do something like what you want with a loop:

```
let rawValues = {};
for (i = 0; i < filterList.length; i++) { 
  rawValues[`${filterList[i].filterLabel}${i}`] =  filterList[i].selectedOption;
}
```

Which should give you something like this:

```
{
   filterLabel1: selectedOption,
   filterLabel2: selectedOption,
   filterLabel3: selectedOption
}
```

Can you guarantee that the filterLabel will always be unique?

Comment: you probably missed some details, first of all, I specified that the object name would be UNIQUE, I used the same just for the sake of the example

Comment: the user below offered a working solution, similiar to yours, it's all about using a ForEach instead!

Comment: My bad; I missed the unique disclaimer.  I got stuck up on the invalid object.  A For loop should do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {};
this.filterList.forEach(s => {
  result[s.filterLabel] = s.selectedOption;
});
```

you can use reduce to achieve the same result:

```
var result = this.filterList.reduce((prev, next) => {
  return {...prev, [next.filterLabel]:next.selectedOption}
}, {});
```